# Create New Role like "Employee_Delete" and assign to specific User

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am new to this `asp.net`  and SQL. Here, i want to create a new role called `Employee_Delete` by using SQL server management studios. i have already database `payrol`and a table called `aspnet_Roles` where all the roles ate listed. I Want this newly created role to appear in the same list. And then, When a user is assigned this role, then he would be able to delete the existing employee. And also the process to define that role so that it can perform its task i.e. in this case deletion.
I have gone through googling this problem but didn't get this exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
exec aspnet_Roles_CreateRole
@ApplicationName  = 'Application name as shown in your project',
@RoleName         = 'RoleName
```

This is the actual query needed to create new role in the existing 'aspnet_Roles' from the SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Membership` and have enabled `Roles`, you can simply call `Roles.CreateRole ("Employee_Delete")` and add user to the role by calling `Roles.AddUserToRole("username", "Employee_Delete")`